# (Firefox bug) Font is sloppy when transformed

Tags: css, firefox, animation, transform

***This question was orginally related to FontAwesome, but is a general firefox problem.***

So i'm using the class `fa-spin` that will spin the icon, [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#spinning) you can find some examples of it.

Here is the spinning css file:

```
// Spinning Icons
// --------------------------

.#{$fa-css-prefix}-spin {
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
  0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
  0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

Now all works fine in chrome and IE10, however it doesn't in firefox :
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXEH4/1/).
When you run it for the first time it looks just good, but try the interact with the site(for example: scroll or run the script again in jsFiddle). The animation becomes all jittery. 
 I have no idea what could cause this strange behavior, hope that anyone could help me.

**Edit**

The problem occurs on Windows 7 32-bit and 25.0 version of Firefox(No add-ons).
However it does work at my home PC, where it also has Windows 7 32-bit 25.0 firefox.
An preview how it looks on my screen:
 [image]
Note that it works for the first couple of seconds but after it will get jittery (this stuttering is because my .gif is bad).

---

**See my answer for more information**

Comment: Any reason the keyframes end at 359 and not 360 degree?

Comment: This is a long shot but you could try to write the keyframes like so: @-webkit-keyframes spin { from { code goes here } to { code goes here } }

Comment: @Josh This is the default code from FontAwesome. I did not see much difference between 360 or 359, so no need to modifie it. And 'from - to'  acts the same as '0% - 100%', tryed that :)

Comment: Hmm, I was just throwing some radical ideas out there ha. The problem I am having is I don't see any glitching or jumpy animations in IE, Firefox, or Chrome. What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 32-bit. Even when you scroll(For example: in the css box) in jsFiddle, you don't see any problems?

Comment: Yeah I didn't see anything, even when I went into /show view it still looked fine.

Comment: Restarted my PC and still have the same problem... This is very odd. Let's see if others also don't see this.

Comment: Yea this should be an interesting one, I did notice the spin animations jumped ever so slightly once but when I changed the rotate to 360 it removed that. Hopefully someone has some good input!

Comment: I have some issues on both Firefox and Chrome. On Firefox, the element does one full spin then starts to shake (still rotating). With Chrome it shakes from the very beginning.

Comment: @MichałRybak and MilchePatern, could you add your browser version?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit, all major browsers, it spins OK on Firefox 24.0  **Aye, check for third-party-plugins and third-party-cookies on your 'problematic' browser**. Yes, this comment is helpful.

Comment: There are no Add-ons/plugins and i've tryed to remove all my cookies, but i still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before you want to add this 'hack', you should first try to update your driver**

What i did notice is that IE and Chrome actually makes the text blurry, which FF doesn't. I thought of using the blur filter, but that didn't work. Also the font width didn't stayed the same, so i needed something that or reminded the client of his width or force the width to be static at all time.

I came across the SVG filter XML url, that was special for Firefox 10+ and Firefox on android. I tryed to apply this to my element and my problem was completly gone!
i did use `<feColorMatrix type=saturate values=1/>` so the saturate filter didn't take away the colors.

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'saturate\' values=\'1\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

When adding this to the `.fa-spin` class that FontAwesome uses, it'll work on every spinning element.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXEH4/4/)**